# How to recreate partitions, like system_a?

Tags: xiaomi, partitions, ab-partition

I deleted the `system_a` partition on my Xiaomi device, and when flashing GSI, it says:

```
E:\platform-tools_r34.0.5-windows\platform-tools>fastboot erase system
Erasing 'system'                                   FAILED (remote: 'Partition doesn't exist')
fastboot: error: Command failed
```